# Make Kubernetes Service Accessible Externally

Tags: docker, kubernetes, coreos, google-kubernetes-engine, flannel

We have a private kubernetes cluster running on a baremetal CoreOS cluster (with Flannel for network overlay) with private addresses.

On top of this cluster we run a kubernetes ReplicationController and Service for elasticsearch. To enable load-balancing, this service has a ClusterIP defined - which is also a private IP address: 10.99.44.10 (but in a different range to node IP addresses).

The issue that we face is that we wish to be able to connect to this ClusterIP from *outside* the cluster. As far as we can tell this private IP is not contactable from other machines in our private network...

How can we achieve this?

---

The IP addresses of the nodes are:

```
 node 1  - 192.168.77.102
 node 2  - 192.168.77.103
```

.

and this is how the Service, RC and Pod appear with kubectl:

```
NAME            LABELS          SELECTOR              IP(S)           PORT(S)
elasticsearch   <none>          app=elasticsearch     10.99.44.10     9200/TCP


CONTROLLER     CONTAINER(S)    IMAGE(S)       SELECTOR            REPLICAS
elasticsearch  elasticsearch   elasticsearch  app=elasticsearch   1


NAME                       READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
elasticsearch-swpy1         1/1       Running   0          26m
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `type` of your Service.

http://docs.k8s.io/v1.0/user-guide/services.html#external-services

If you are on bare metal, you don't have a LoadBalancer integrated.  You can use NodePort to get a port on each VM, and then set up whatever you use for load-balancing to aim at that port on any node.

Comment: Thanks for the response tim. When you say "that port on any node" - do you mean point the LB at *all* nodes?  then what happens if the node that receives the traffic is not running that particular service? will it use kube-proxy to redirect it to the correct node?

Comment: Sorry "that port" means the nodePort that was allocated for your service port.  It will be a new port number that we allocate internally (so that you can have the same number on every machine).  That will trap into kube-proxy and will redirect to the service, regardless of which node.

Comment: many thanks tim (and sorry for very late reply). We achieved this by setting a static NodePort number in the RC configuration file `type: NodePort` `nodePort: 30222`. We then pointed haproxy at the two nodes (on port 30222) to allow high availability.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nodeport, but also use hostport for some daemonsets and deployments and hostnetwork to give a pod total node network access

IIRC, if you have a recent enough kubernetes, each node can forward traffic to the internal network, so if you create the correct routing in your clients/switch, you can access the internal network by delivering those TCP/IP packages to one node. The node will then receive the package and SNAT+forward to the clusterIP or podIP.

Finally, barebone can use now [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/) for kubernetes loadbalancer, that is mostly using this last feature in a more automatic and redundant way